# mount.nfs: Connection timed out error when trying to add and nfs drive to Ubuntu server

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, nfs

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.03 and i am trying to connect an NFS drive from a WD PR4100 nas.
The annoying thing - i had this all working yesterday, then today it just wont connect. I am using cockpit and was using the gui to mount it.

Now i just get a `mount.nfs: Connection timed out error`. I have tried adding it via the terminal, which doesn't work. I have tried a ping to my nas and that works ok. So i am not sure why it cannot now seem to connect to it when trying to mount the drive. I know the PR4100 only works with nfsvers=3, which i have added. All settings are correct on the Nas, as nothing there has changed.

The only thing i can remember doing since is connecting a new local hard drive, though i have no idea if that would cause issues.

[Here's an image of the settings and the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ihN.jpg)

I have spent most of the day trying to figure out why its not working and its driving me crazy. I should note i have only used Ubuntu/Linux for the past few days, so i'm total noob!

Edit*

Regarding my comment below. I woke up this morning to the nfs not working again. So i tried to factory reset the nas again but unfortunately that did not work, so i am back to square one.

Edit #2*

I had link aggregation turned on and set up via my router. I decided to switch ports to see if that was messing things up, now it connects first time every time. So i guess Ubuntu doesn't play nice with link aggregation. If this actually fixes the issue i will update my answer below so others can find it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to factory reset my nas. Nothing had actually changed on the nas however and all the settings are still the same. Hopefully i dont run into this issue again.

Edit*

For anyone else with the same issue, Ubuntu does not play nice with Link Aggregation. This was the source of all my issues, once turned off, everything works correctly.